# Remove A Scratch From The Lid Of A Unibody Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, unibody

Is there a way to remove a slim scratch from the lid of a three month old unibody Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use car wax on my MacBook lid/palm rest. It works great. It even leaves it super shiny and smooth. I do it every now and again. I do the same to my iPhone and MagicMouse. I'm a bit of a neat freak in that way, but I figure I spent a lot on these so I want to keep them in good shape.

Comment: Is it a particular type or any car wax will do ?